# Avoiding Duplicate Repository Declaration in Multi Module Gradle Project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, multi-module

Lets say I have two projects in a multimodule gradle (4.2) repository with the following configurations:

Project A build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile (group: 'org.example', name: 'dependency-of-vast-importance', version: '17.2') {

}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://download.example.org
    }
}
```

Project B build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(":projectA")
  compile (group: 'org.anotherdependency', name: 'anotherdependency', version: '1.0')
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://download.anotherdependency.org
    }
}
```

With this configuration, Project B will fail to build -claiming in cannot find dependency-of-vast-importance.

So far, the only "solution" I have found for successfully completing the build requires writing the build.gradle for projectB like:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(":projectA")
  compile (group: 'org.anotherdependency', name: 'anotherdependency', version: '1.0')
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://download.anotherdependency.org
    }
    maven {
        url "http://download.example.org
    }
}
```

This approach is worthless because it requires that I copy the repository declarations for ProjectA to all other projects that depend on it -which defeats the purpose of dependency management and modules.

How can I avoid specifying all the repositories necessary for Project A in Project B's build.gradle?

Comment: You have to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use in root build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.anotherdependency.org' }
        maven { url 'http://download.example.org' }
    }
}
```

This code will apply repositories to all projects

Comment: This is what I ultimately ended up doing -wish gradle had the ability to derive dependencies from specific repositories.